# Obtaining a value from dictionary given certain condition

Tags: python, dictionary, boolean, key, anaconda

I have three lists (esferas, vdif and valores), forming a dictionary. I want to assign to a new variable, one value from valores, given the value of vdif, which is equal to the maximum or minimum of another list (small). I have tried the next, but it's not working:

```
    d = dict(zip(valores, zip(esferas,vdif)))
    vsup = d['valores' == max[small]]
    vinf = d['valores' == min[small]]
    s = d['esferas' == min[dif]]
```

These are the results I would like to have:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwxsG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
if condition1:
    vsup = d['valores']
```

You're trying currently to access `True` or `False` keys in your dictionary with your test. You need to check condition and then access value

```
'valores'==max[small]
```

is a boolean test yielding `True` and `False`

Comment: That is not what I want to do, it is not an if. I hope this picture make it more clear:
https://gyazo.com/b6a5675a0989925c35a7dd4604232937